# ¿Como puedeo reproducir sonido en lenguaje lua?

Tags: lua

Es posible reproducir sonido en lua(desde su libreria) o es posible reproducir directamente desde el OS algo como `os.playsound()` , si hay una manera porfavor  pueden ayudarme?

Gracias De Antemano!

Answer (score 0):

directamente no... tendrías que usar C para conseguirlo, la idea sería crear una especie de audio binder

```
#ifndef AUDIOBINDER_H
#define AUDIOBINDER_H

#include "binder.h"

class AudioBinder
{
public:
    AudioBinder(lua_State *L);

private:
    static int Sound_create(lua_State *L);
    static int Sound_destruct(lua_State *L);
    static int Sound_getLength(lua_State *L);
    static int Sound_play(lua_State *L);
    static int Sound_setListenerPosition(lua_State *L);

    static int SoundChannel_destruct(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_stop(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_setPosition(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_getPosition(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_setVolume(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_getVolume(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_setPitch(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_getPitch(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_isPlaying(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_setPaused(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_isPaused(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_setLooping(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_isLooping(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_setWorldPosition(lua_State *L);
    static int SoundChannel_getStreamId(lua_State *L);
};


#endif
```

Puedes chequear estas bibliotecas que son open source:

[audiobinder.h](https://github.com/gideros/gideros/blob/05b06619421d1de13faf7f4e9792a6cbf0567f63/luabinding/audiobinder.h)

[audiobinder.cpp](https://github.com/gideros/gideros/blob/05b06619421d1de13faf7f4e9792a6cbf0567f63/luabinding/audiobinder.cpp)

[luabinding - repositorio github](https://github.com/gideros/gideros/tree/05b06619421d1de13faf7f4e9792a6cbf0567f63/luabinding)